# Calculating percentage of total in SQL Server with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a two tables

```
user_id    assignment_ts        experiment_id   experiment_assignment
----------------------------------------------------------------------
1         20190106 12:00:05          1              test
1         20190304 01:45:23          2              test
2         20190107 03:45:12          1             control
3         20190311 01:45:23          2              test

user_id      subscription_event   event_ts
----------------------------------------------------
1                trial_start      20190106 12:00:04
1           subscription_start    20190115 10:03:05
2               trial_start       20190107 03:45:10
3               trial_start       20190311 01:45:20


SELECT 
    t.experiment_id, t.experiment_assignment, t.subscription_event,
    CAST((COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t.experiment_id, t.experiment_assignment, t.subscription_event)) AS DECIMAL) /tot_usr_count * 100
FROM
    (SELECT 
          e1.experiment_id, s1.user_id, e1.experiment_assignment, 
          s1.subscription_event,
          COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY e1.experiment_id, e1.experiment_assignment) AS tot_usr_count 
      FROM 
          experiments e1
      INNER JOIN 
          subscriptions s1 ON s1.user_id = e1.user_id) AS t
```

And my result looks like this

```
experiment_id experiment_assignment  subscription_event        per_cent
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                control                trial_start         100.00000000000
1                 test                subscription_start     50.00000000000
1                 test                  trial_start          50.00000000000
2                 test                subscription_start     33.33333333300
2                 test                  trial_start          66.66666666600
2                 test                  trial_start          66.66666666600
```

But I need my result to look like this, how can this be done? I tried to pivot but I could not do it! Is there any easier way?

```
experiment_id   test_conversion_rate    control_conversion_rate
---------------------------------------------------------------
    1                100%                       0%
    2                 50%                     (null)
```

Comment: Pivot is the easy way... show your pivot attempts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking:

```
select e.experiment_id,
       count(*) as num_users,
       count(s.user_id) as num_subscribers,
       count(s.user_id) * 1.0 / count(*)
from experiments e left join
     subscriptions s
     on s.user_id = e.user_id and
        s.subscrxiption_event = 'subscription_start' and
        s.event_ts >= e.assignment_ts
group by e.experiment_id;
```

I don't see any need for window functions in this query.

Note:  The above assumes that only subscriptions after the "assignment' are valid, although that is not mentioned explicitly in the question.

It also assumes that users cannot subscribe more than once.  If that is possibly, just use `count(distinct s.user_id)` for the subscribers and `count(distinct e.user_id)` for the number of users.

Also, I am not a fan of converting numbers to percents.  You can of course do that, but it does not seem germane to the question.

Answer (score 0):

How about cast to varchar and add '%' to it?

```
SELECT 
    t.experiment_id, t.experiment_assignment, t.subscription_event,
    CAST( (CAST((COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY t.experiment_id, t.experiment_assignment, t.subscription_event)) AS DECIMAL) /tot_usr_count * 100) AS VARCHAR(100)) + '%'
FROM
    (SELECT 
          e1.experiment_id, s1.user_id, e1.experiment_assignment, 
          s1.subscription_event,
          COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY e1.experiment_id, e1.experiment_assignment) AS tot_usr_count 
      FROM 
          experiments e1
      INNER JOIN 
          subscriptions s1 ON s1.user_id = e1.user_id) AS t
```